# How To Reduce Prometheus(Federation) Scrape Duration

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus

I have a Prometheus federation with 2 prometheus' servers - one per Kubernetes cluster and a central to rule them all.

Over time the scrape durations increase. At some point, the scrape duration exceeds the timeout duration and then metrics get lost and alerts fire.

I’m trying to reduce the scrape duration by dropping metrics but this is an uphill battle and more like sisyphus then Prometheus.

Does anyone know a way to reduce the scrape time without losing metrics and without having to drop more and more as times progresses?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In my understanding of prometheus, the load of datas should not have any effect on th scraping, maybe on the request as it will have to look into more datas... How did you create you kebernetes and where (gke,eks, other...)

Answer (score 4):

Per Prometheus' [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#configuration-file), these settings determine the *global* timeout and alerting rules evaluation frequency:

```
global:
  # How frequently to scrape targets by default.
  [ scrape_interval: <duration> | default = 1m ]

  # How long until a scrape request times out.
  [ scrape_timeout: <duration> | default = 10s ]

  # How frequently to evaluate rules.
  [ evaluation_interval: <duration> | default = 1m ]
```

...and for each scrape job the [configuration](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#%3Cscrape_config%3E) allows setting *job-specific* values:

```
# The job name assigned to scraped metrics by default.
job_name: <job_name>

# How frequently to scrape targets from this job.
[ scrape_interval: <duration> | default = <global_config.scrape_interval> ]

# Per-scrape timeout when scraping this job.
[ scrape_timeout: <duration> | default = <global_config.scrape_timeout> ]
```

Not knowing more about the number of targets and number of metrics per target...I can suggest to try to configure appropriate `scrape_timeout` per job and adjust the global `evaluation_interval` accordingly.

Another option, in combination with the suggestion above or on its own, can be to have prometheus instances dedicated on scraping non-overlapping set of targets. Thus, making it possible to scale prometheus and to have different `evaluation_interval` per set of targets. For example, longer `scrape_timeout` and less frequent `evaluation_interval` (higher value) for jobs that take longer so that they don't affect other jobs.

Also, check if an exporter isn't misbehaving by accumulating metrics over time instead of just providing current readings at the time of scraping - otherwise, the list of what's returned to prometheus will keep on growing over time.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't recommended to build data replication on top of [Prometheus federation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/), since it doesn't scale with the number of active time series as could be seen in the described case. It is better setting up data replication via [Prometheus remote_write protocol](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/#remote-storage-integrations). For example, add the following lines to Prometheus config in order to enable data replication to [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) remote storage located at the given `url`:

```yaml
remote_write:
  - url: http://victoriametrics-host:8428/api/v1/write
```

The following docs may be useful for further reading:

- [remote_write config docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#remote_write)
- [supported remote storage systems in Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/integrations/#remote-endpoints-and-storage)
- [remote_write tuning docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/remote_write/)